# Adding characters to the first of lines with 60 or more characters

Tags: notepad++

I want to adding character to the first of lines with 60 or more characters, how can I do this?

I used this `(.{60})\s` to search, but I don't know what to put in replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a capturing group starting at begin of a line. You'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.{60})`
- Replace with: `added text\1`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

*is resulting in:*

[image]

The replacement `addedtext\1` is beginning with some text and adds the text stored by the capturing group.

Some additional information about reinserting text matched by capturing groups in the replacement text:

> The `\1` syntax for backreferences in the replacement text is borrowed from the syntax for backreferences in the regular expression. `\1` through `\9` are supported by the JGsoft applications, Delphi, Perl (though deprecated), Python, Ruby, PHP, R, Boost, and Tcl.

> `$1` through `$99` for single-digit and double-digit backreferences are supported by the JGsoft applications, Delphi, .NET, Java, JavaScript, VBScript, PCRE2, PHP, Boost, std::regex, and XPath.

[Quoted from: Numbered Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)

Notepad++ regular expressions use the Boost regular expression library v1.80 (as of NPP v8.4.7), which is based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) syntax.